# UnixTimestamp to Date in Java

Tags: java

My code to convert Unix timestamp to date in Java:

```
String s = "1255485965825";
long d = Long.valueOf(s) * 1000L;
str = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date(d));

My output:08/05/2784
Expected Result:10/13/2009
```

Why I am getting future date and completely wrong result.Please help me out.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Your input string, `"1255485965825"`, already seems to include milliseconds.  Thus, you shouldn't be multiplying by `1000`.

Answer (score 1):

you are multiplying by 1000. It is already in millis since epoch, just pass in the `Long.valueOf(s)`

Answer (score 0):

The time-stamp is already in milliseconds, don't multiply by 1000!

```
String s = "1255485965825";
long d = Long.valueOf(s);
String str = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date(d));
System.out.println(str);
```

Gives the correct output here.

Comment: Ya removed it.It Worked.Thank you.But in which case it should be multiplied by 1000.

Comment: When the value is in seconds since epoch.